# Document/CosmosDB .Net client "DISTINCT" query error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a collection that contains documents with the following structure:

```
{
    "Identifier": 1,
    "Values": {
        "value1": "33806",
        "value2": "10",
        "value3": "0"
    },
   ...
}
```

I have created a UDF to extract the keys from the `Values` dictionary:

```
function getKeys(dictionary) {
    let result = [];
    for (var key in dictionary) {
        result.push(key);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And I have a query that uses the UDF to find all the distinct keys in the `Values` dictionary.  The following code calls CosmosDB using the `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` nuget package library:

```
var query = $@"
    SELECT DISTINCT
    VALUE i
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
        VALUE
        {{
             'keys': udf.getKeys(c.Values), 
             'id': c.Identifier
        }}
        FROM c
        WHERE c.Identifier = @Identifier
    ) AS dt
    JOIN i in dt.keys";

    var parameters = new SqlParameterCollection(new[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@Identifier", identifier)
    });

    var documentQuery = store.Query(new SqlQuerySpec(query, parameters));
```

This is running against the Azure CosmosDB emulator.  The query works fine when I run it through the UI on `http://localhost:8081`.

When running the query through the .NET client, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BadRequestException: Message:
>   {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":25,"end":33},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax
>   error, incorrect syntax near 'DISTINCT'."}]}, Windows/10.0.16299
>   documentdb-netcore-sdk/1.9.1 --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800A0B00

I have not yet tried this against *real* CosmosDB, however the fact that this works in the data explorer makes me think it isn't a capability issue with the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have not yet tried this against real CosmosDB, however the fact that
> this works in the data explorer makes me think it isn't a capability
> issue with the emulator.

The `distinct` is supported in SQL by cosmos db emulator or real version. (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6719531-provide-support-for-distinct?page=1&per_page=20)

I tested your code with `documentdb-netcore-sdk v.2.0.0` and it works fine. According to this issue doc, the bug seems to be solved in 2.0.0-preview or later version. You could update version of your package.

Comment: Cheers for this!  Looks like the update was published 5 days ago!  Will give it a go now